# JQ query to filter entries using a membership condition over an external array passed into parameter (with --arg)

Tags: arrays, filter, jq, membership

Given a test file test.json:

```
[
  {
    "name": "foo",
    "key1": "val3,val2,val1",
    "category": "thefoocategory"
  },
  {
    "name": "bar",
    "key1": "val2",
    "category": "thebarcategory"
  }
]
```

and given:

```
str="val1,val2,val3"
```

I want to filter from the file the "name" attributes for which the associated "key1" attribute, seen as an array, hold all the values (order of elements doesn't matter) of "str" seen as an array [foo]

I try with easier use cases (replacing "valX" by "X" in the test file)  but I am stuck at specifying the condition of membership.

Something like:

```
cat test1 | jq -r --arg v "1,2,3" '[.[] | select($v | split(",") | all((.key1 | split(",")) | index(.) != null))]'
```

It fails (Cannot index string with string "key1") but I can't really figure out why replacing `(.key1|split(","))` with [1,2,3] produces a result.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the list at commas into an array, then use `all` with `IN` to test the containedness for all items.

```bash
str="val1,val2,val3"
jq --arg str "$str" '($str / ",") as $arr
  | map(select(. as $dot | $arr | all(IN(($dot.key1 / ",")[]))).name)
'
```

```json
[
  "foo"
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/m7C3S5YRZEJ)

Comment: I would have never thought of this approach, but if I now use `str="val1,val3"`, I expect the same result `["foo"]` (associated key1 contains val1, val2 and val3 so it contains val1 and val3 in particular) but I got none (`[]`).

Maybe my initial question was not so clear: its not about array equality but about external array elements being contained in another array (read from file) in no particular order.

Comment: Updated: now testing for containedness using  `all` with `IN` (`contains` would also yield `true` on substrings).

Comment: Using jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe, I get for this one:

`jq: error: IN/1 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
($str / ",") as $arr | map(select(. as $dot | $arr | all(IN(($dot.key1 / ",")[]))).name)                                                         
jq: 1 compile error`

Comment: `IN` was introduced with [jq 1.6](https://github.com/jqlang/jq/releases/tag/jq-1.6) (Nov 2, 2018). Using jq 1.5, you can either define it based on `any` yourself (`def IN(s): any(s == .; .);`, taken from [builtin.jq](https://github.com/jqlang/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L279) in the current version's source code) or refactor its usage itself (`all(any(($dot.key1 | splits(",")) == .; .))`, see https://jqplay.org/s/ryZKM_Prui5)

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly (I use the suggestion with the refactor proposal). My real use case file holds much more entries and additional attributes filters, to this regard (that I have manage to reintroduce) but regarding the number of entries in the JSON file, I was wondering if the solution was as efficient as possible ?

Comment: If you have to do such tests frequently or repeatedly, you could precompute and save the partitioned values of `.key1` somewhere, so it doesn't get computed on every iteration. Other than that, I can't think of any improvement regarding efficiency. But maybe others can have a less biased look.

Comment: By that, do you mean using --argjson with a real JSON array instead of using --arg (and split later in the jq filter body) in the command line ?

Comment: That one you only read once, so it doesn't really matter. I mean something along the lines of `map(.key1_split = .key1 / ",")`, and then from then on just use `IN(.key1_split[])` instead.

Comment: Speaking of efficiency, I just realized that the regex splitter `splits` somehow sneaked into my [comment on how to refactor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77874726/77874803#comment137288773_77874803). I actually wanted to use `split` (without "s"), or simply `/` instead, and then employ it just like before as `(…)[]` to iterate over the results (as both produce arrays, not a stream like `splits` does). Splitting by regex is way more costly than doing it by static strings. So, the refactoring should have read: `all(any(($dot.key1 / ",")[] == .; .))` and https://jqplay.org/s/0n1pHQnHuxI

Answer (score 0):

For clarity, I'd use `all/2`:

```
jq -r --arg v "val1,val2,val3" '
   ($v / ",") as $values
   | .[]
   | select( (.key1 / ",") as $kv
             | all( $values[]; IN($kv[]) ))
   | .name
```

Comment: This would be for 1.6x JQ version, I am using 1.5x version but bet I can use the alternative construct using the any keyword as suggested earlier !

Comment: @FreeBSDEnthousiast  - Just add the def for IN/1, i.e. `def IN(s): any(s == .; .);`.  Or, since jq 1.5 is very old (2015), feel free to upgrade :-)

Comment: I just figured out how to inline the def in the jq body but when executing this code with the exposed data file, I am not getting the expected result: I get foo (expected) and bar (not expected). 
My command line is `cat test.json | jq -r --arg v "val1,val2,val3" 'def IN(s): any(s == .; .); ($v / ",") as $values | .[] | select( all(.key1 / "," | .[]; IN($values[]))).name'`